# Given $f(x)$'s graph, how can I obtain $g(x)$'s graph knowing $ (f(x) )^2 = g(x)$

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

The equation $$ f(x) = \frac{x+2}{x-2}$$ has two asymptotes: $x=2$ and $y=1$. $f(x)$'s graph looks sort of like a distorted hyperbola. So, after figuring that out -- through limits or whatever --, how can I find what the graph of $g(x) = f(x)^2$ looks like?

Comment: It is an hyperbole, translated not distorted. Notice also that $f(-2)=0$. You can try to draft $f$ and then use that $|f|<g$ when $|f|>1$ and $|f|>g$ for $|f|<1$ to start drawing $g$ .

Comment: bad choice of words haha yes, I know what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{4}{x-2}
$$
so it is a scaled and shifted hyperbola, as you correctly note, with vertex at $(2,1)$. Please see the graph below:

[image: graph of f(x)]

When you square the function, we get 
$$
g(x) = f(x)^2 = \left(1+\frac{4}{x-2}\right)^2
$$
on a very high level you expect the vertical asymptote at $x=2$ to stay, and the right piece of the hyperbola not to globally change behavior, but the lower-left half of the hyperbola should "reflect over the $y$-axis" (reflection is not exact here since shape will change, but high level it should approach $+\infty$ as $x \to 2^-$.)

Note that as $x \to -\infty$, you should have $g(x) \to 1-$ (as $f(x) \to 1-$ there, so you expect there would be a parabola-like bend from $1$ at $x\to-\infty$ and $+\infty$ at $x \to 2^-$, with some relative minimum somewhere in between, which you can find by solving 
$$
0 = g'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x) \iff f'(x) = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad f(x)=0
$$

Indeed, here is the graph:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't $g(x)$ approach $1$ as $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing!

Comment: Also the derivative condition should be $2f(x)f'(x) = 0$ as you said, simplifying down to $f(x)f'(x) = 0$. But other than these 2 quick fixes, this is a nice answer! The main take away should be that if you take a function $f(x)$ and form the composition $h(f(x)) = f^2(x)$, where $h$ is the squaring function, the domain of the composition is the same as the original function. I.e. vertical asymptotes stay in the same place. If all the horizontal asympotes are positive, then squaring wont affect those either (actually this last line isn't true. it's true here because the asymptote is the # $1$)

Comment: @DWade64 fixed both, please feel free to edit directly next time, obvious mistake :)

Comment: Great answer, guys! Thanks a lot :D